# How do I fix a Stubborn syntax error in my python project?

Tags: python

I'm working on a school project and I've almost got it done. Doing a hangman game. for the "else:" command below print (char) on line 32 I keep getting a syntax error and nothing I've tried so far fixes it and the compiler wont tell me what the problem is besides it being a syntax error

```
import time
Name =input("What is your name?")
print ("Hello,"+Name,"Time to play hangman")
print( "")
#wait for 1 second
time.sleep(1)
print("Start guessing...")
time.sleep(0.5)

#here we set the secret

word = "ball"

#creates an variable with an empty value

guesses = ""

#determine the number of turns
turns =10

#create a while loop

#check if the turns are more than zero
while turns > 0:         

#make a counter that starts with zero
  Failed =0
  #for every character in secret_word
  for char in word:
      if char in guesses:
        print (char,)
        else:
            print  (  "_", )    
            failed += 1    

          print ("You won")
          break
          print()
          guess = input ("guess a character:")
  guesses +=guess
  if guess not in word
  turns -=1
  print ("Wrong")
  print ("You have", turns, "more guesses")
  if turns ==0:
    print ("You Lose the Word was",word)
```

Comment: `else` needs to be indented the same amount as the matching `if`. The indentation for the rest of your code looks a bit off as well.

Comment: ok I fixed that and re worked the indentation on my code and its working now, thank you

Comment: I recommend using a linter like [flake8](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/). These kinds of tools will help you find issues like this early on. You can even configure lots of code editors to run them dynamically for you. Your code has a number of similar problems.

Comment: actually now its saying "guess" is not defined. didn't I define it as input tho?

Comment: You define `guess` in the else clause of your conditional, which means it isn't always available by the time you exit the conditional (consider if the `true` clause executes, not the `else`).

Comment: your problem is still the same. indentation is incorrect